# Reading more than 8 bits from an SI7021 sensor

Tags: i2c, sensor, python-3

**I am using the [Si7021-A20](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7021-A20.pdf) sensor on a Raspberry Pi Zero WH** (headless, controlled via ssh and VNC). I want to get readings using Python (version 3). However, **I have a very hard time to actually get more than a single byte of data.**

Here's what I have now (SI7021-test2-doublebyteread-nohold.py):

```
from smbus import SMBus
import time    

# Get I2C bus
bus = SMBus(1)

#Measure Relative Humidity, No Hold Master Mode 0xF5
bus.write_byte(0x40, 0xF5)
# SI7021 address, 0x40  Read 2 bytes, Humidity
time.sleep(0.1)
data0 = bus.read_byte(0x40)
time.sleep(0.1)
data1 = bus.read_byte(0x40)

print(data0)
print(data1)

# Convert the data
humidity = ((data0 * 256 + data1) * 125 / 65536.0) - 6
print(humidity)
```

this gives in Thonny (and similar from the command line)

```
========================= RESTART =========================
>>> %Run SI7021-test2-doublebyteread-nohold.py
104
104
44.9796142578125
```

44.9 is actually a realistic value, matching another device's reading.

**Note, that the two bytes are having the same value. This is always the case.** If the humidity increases, both value increase to the same value.Now I fail to get that second byte out of the sensor.

I tried the "Hold" and "No hold" modes, played with the timings, used smbus2, and also with the I2C blocks like:

```
rh = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x40, 0xE5, 2)
```

But this gives

```
>>> %Run SI7021-test1-i2c-block.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/SI7021-test1-i2c-block.py", line 10, in <module>
    rh = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x40, 0xE5, 2)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

**How to get that second byte as valid reading?**

Note: There are various blog posts, forum threads and other resources, but no I found helped me beyond what I describe here.

Comment: Here is my working code http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_Si7021_py There is a difference between SMBus and I2C.  SMBus has a richer command set but is strangely enough far less flexible.

Comment: @joan You can bet I already came across your site. I have not yet been able to run, though mostly because of my poor python skills. I'll come back with more results.

Comment: @joan Ok, that was all my faults. I did save it with another name than given, and modules seem to be picky about their names, even casings. Then I needed to start the demon as stated in the intro screen. Now it works. However, I wonder, do I need a demon to use I2C generally?

Comment: No you don't need a daemon to use I2C, that's just how my software works (it lets you run the script on another machine whilst talking to a Pi over the network).  You need to see how that example code reads multiple bytes and see if you can adapt your code in a similar fashion.

Comment: @joan I could not figure out the necessary code to work without the daemon, I still got those weird error on write. Eventually, this is for a hobby project only, anyway. However, I have written up my odissey in a blog post at https://qrys.ch/reading-14bit-from-an-si7021-temperature-and-humidity-sensor/, if your interested. I give you credit there for your module. If you write up an answer here mentioning your module, I'll gladly accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit for the solution goes to @joan. **Key here seems to omit the I2C and SMBus python implementations and query the sensor via the [pipgio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) library.**

Using @joan's pigpio library and his Si7021.py script I finally got a solution that uses the full resolution.

I've written in detail in [my blog post about how I used the library and script](https://qrys.ch/reading-14bit-from-an-si7021-temperature-and-humidity-sensor/), but basically you can do it like this in the terminal:

```
# installing pigpio first
sudo apt-get install pigpio python-pigpio python3-pigpio

# get the Si7021.py script
wget http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/Si7021_py.zip
unzip Si7021_py.zip

# start the pigpiod daemon; -l disables the remote socket interface, it's not needed to read a local sensor
sudo pigpiod -l 
# start the main function in the module
python3 Si7021.py
```